# javaFX mediaPlayer fade out currently playing audio

Tags: java, javafx, audio-player

I'm new to JavaFX and I'm currently developing a game.

I've managed to set background music in the app using the `MediaPlayer` class.

Now what I need is to create a method that makes the song fade out (instead of stopping instantly).

I've been stuck in reading about transitions but don't really understand how to use them.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) class can change any JavaFX property.  By default, the property’s value is interpolated toward the target value, which (I believe) will provide the fade you desire:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10),
        new KeyValue(mediaPlayer.volumeProperty(), 0)));
timeline.play();
```

The KeyValue specifies the property you want to change (volume), and the target value (zero, that is, mute) for that property.

The KeyFrame specifies the time at which the KeyValue’s value should be in effect.

Comment: You should probably also stop the `MediaPlayer` in the `onFinished` event of the `Timeline`...

Comment: Wow great! one more question: How can I make the program wait until the fade out is over to perform the next line of code?

Comment: The easiest way is to create a Thread whose Runnable sleeps for the duration, then invokes the subsequent JavaFX code in a different Runnable passed to `Platform.runLater`.  There are other ways, but it depends on what you want to do after the fade finishes.